# MingW c++ compile Error Win 7 x64

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, windows-7, mingw

I'm trying to compile a simple C++ HelloWorld example on my Win 7 x64 machine with the mingw compiler.
I downloaded the automated installer here: http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=2435

After setting the required paths in the system environment variables i was trying to get the compiler to work with a simple HelloWorld example. Sadly, it always crashes with the following error dialog (i am using a german windows, so the translation may not be perfect):

```
cc1plus.exe - Application error
The application could not be started correctly (0xc000003b).
Click "OK" to close the application.
```

Below the verbose compile output

```
W:\Timo\workspace\c++\HelloWorld>gcc HelloWorld.cpp -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=d:/workspace/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-4.5.2/configure --enable-languages=c,c++,ada,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-dwarf2 --ena
ble-shared --enable-libgomp --disable-win32-registry --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --disable-werror -
-build=mingw32 --prefix=/mingw
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.5.2 (GCC)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=i386' '-march=i386'
d:/workspace/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/cc1plus.exe -quiet -v -iprefix     d:\workspace\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/ He
lloWorld.cpp -quiet -dumpbase HelloWorld.cpp -mtune=i386 -march=i386 -auxbase HelloWorld -version -o C:\Users\afro\AppData\Local\Temp\c
czfrXM3.s
```

Thanks in advance.

Timo

Comment: You need to post the *code*, not the error dialog or the compiler output.

Comment: I think 0xc000003b means "incorrect path format". I see that at least one path mixes '\' and '/'. Not sure if it's a problem...

Comment: Use mingw-w64 instead, http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. But that didn't do the trick. I've used severall x64 mingw installations but the result was always the same. The path-thing didn't work either :(
@DeadMG: It's not the source code which is wrong here. I dont even get the compiler to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the problem. The file i tried to compile was saved on my NAS-Server which requires a login to access the files. I was able to access the file via console, the compiler obviously did not. After moving the source files on my local hdd, the compiler started working.

Comment: I have same error when i try to build qt project. The project directory was on mapped network drive. Problem solved when I move to generic drive (not network mapped). My network drive does not require any login to access. The path differnce was only one drive letter. There is no fix need for project. Seems it is internal mingw restriction.